# Repeating a function with another function

Tags: python, function

for an assignment we needed to make a function that flipped a coin and another to flip it 100 times. I was able to make a function that flipped a coin, but got stuck when trying to call it a 100 times with another function. This is what I have right now:

```
import random

def TC():
    face = random.randint(0,1)
    if face == 1:
        return "head"
    else:
        return "tail"

print TC()

def ply(flips):
    for i in range(flips):
        return TC()


print ply(100)
```

When I run it it just says 'none.' Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thank You!

Comment: `return` ends the function immediately - even if it's in the first iteration of a loop. Instead of returning, you should do something like append the value to an array and return that after the loop is complete. (I don't see that this code should return `None` btw, it should return either `"head"` or `"tail"` according to the one random flip it actually does).

Comment: I don't see how this code could possibly print "None". Can we have a [mcve]; i.e. formatted code?

Comment: When I run this, it prints `head head` (on separate lines), once for each call.

Comment: Change the `return` inside `ply` to be the `print` or build a list and return that at the end and then print that. Currently `return TC()` will just return after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Just to start, your method naming is very bad. I doubt this is how your professor is teaching you to name methods and variables. It's ugly, against Python standards and hard to read I suggest you take some time and read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it's how python was intended to be written.

So instead of `TC` you should use something like `flip_coin` and instead of `ply` use something like `play_coin_flip` or even simply `play`.

Next I don't know if I'm stepping outside of what you have learned but instead of using `randon.randint` you can use `randon.choice`.

And finally, as others have said, when you return you quit any other execution in a function and return whatever variable you retrun in that statement thus nullifying any other iterations of the loop you're performing. I suggest something like the below as a better program with corrections applied to make it function as intended.

```
from random import choice

faces = ['head', 'tail']

def flip_coin():
    face = choice(faces)
    return face

def play_coin_flip(flips = 1):
    for i in range(flips):
        print(flip_coin)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_coin_flip(100)
```